# binary search built in method is not working for my window form program c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, binary-search

I created a program that uses both linear and binary search method. I use string array.

```cs
private void linearSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string target = linearSearchBox.Text;
    bool found = false;

    for (int x = 0; x < myArray.Length; x++)
    {
        if (myArray[x] == target)
        {
            displayBox2.Text = target + " Found at index " + (x + 1) +
                         "\r\n"; 
            linearSearchBox.Clear();
            linearSearchBox.Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        displayBox2.Text = "Not Found, try again." + "\r\n";
        linearSearchBox.Clear();
        linearSearchBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

this will work, however the binary doest not

```cs
private void BinarySearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Array.Sort(myArray, 0, emptyPtr);

    SearchArray(myArray, binarySearchBox.Text);
}

private void SearchArray(Array array, object value)
{
    Array.Sort(myArray, 0, emptyPtr);
    string target = binarySearchBox.Text;
    int numIndex = Array.BinarySearch(array, target);

    if (numIndex < 0)
    {
        displayBox2.Text = "The element to search for " + target + " is not found.";
    }
    else if(numIndex >= 0)
    {
        displayBox2.Text = "The element to search for " + target+ " is at index: " + numIndex;
    }
}
```

[test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSBVA.png) [test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o31om.png)

Comment: What is `emptyPtr`? Just use `Array.Sort(myArray)`.

Comment: so emptyPtr is a int variable that use to count existing array in myArray

Comment: [Debug your C# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) to inspect the variables and see what happens.

Comment: numIndex turn -21 the target are what i input in thebinarySearchBox

Comment: it is not return either -1 or any positive values

Comment: The documentation of [Array.BinarySearch Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=net-6.0#system-array-binarysearch(system-array-system-object)) says: *" If value is not found and value is less than one or more elements in array, the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value."*. so, you might get other negative values than -1.

Comment: Hard to say, since we do not know what value `target` has and what these is in the array.

Comment: yeah, so the target is basically the input value that stored as binarySearchBox.Text

Comment: SO there is two image that i posted, the blank space on right show the value stored in myArray, while i pass  linear method, it proofs that the array in myArray is matching linearSearchBox.text while ignore the 1:,2:,3: etc.

Comment: I would recommend rewriting your example to a *minimal reproducible* one. Such an example should be shorter than your current one, and should make the problem really easy to find.

Comment: i fixed it by using BinarySearch(Array, Int32, Int32, Object) form, this issues appears before in the Array.Sort(myArray, 0, emptyPtr), i could not run the program by simply using Array.Sort(myArray, emptyPtr);

Comment: Note that you are using the value of another textbox for the binary search.

Comment: should i put them together? , not quite sure what your mean.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the code is performing a binary search in the text box of binarySearchBox, not the value in the text box of ListBox1.

The code that needs to convert the value added to ListBox1 into an Array array for storage.`string[]myArray = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray();`,then search for ListBox1.

Code show as below:

```
private void BinarySearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[]myArray = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray();
        Array.Sort(myArray, 0, emptyPtr);     
        SearchArray(myArray, binarySearchBox.Text);

    }
    private void SearchArray(Array array, object value)
    {
        string[] myArray = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray();
        Array.Sort(myArray, 0, emptyPtr);
        string target = binarySearchBox.Text;
        int numIndex = Array.BinarySearch(array, target);

        if (numIndex < 0)
        {
            displayBox2.Text = "The element to search for " + target + " is not found.";
        }
        else if (numIndex >= 0)
        {
            displayBox2.Text = "The element to search for " + target + " is at index: " + numIndex;
        }
    }

    private void linearSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] myArray = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray();
        string target = linearSearchBox.Text;
        bool found = false;

        for (int x = 0; x < myArray.Length; x++)
        {
            if (myArray[x] == target)
            {
                displayBox2.Text = target + " Found at index " + (x + 1) +
                             "\r\n";
                linearSearchBox.Clear();
                linearSearchBox.Focus();
                return;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            displayBox2.Text = "Not Found, try again." + "\r\n";
            linearSearchBox.Clear();
            linearSearchBox.Focus();
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]